# Cron schedule for running on every thursday and friday of april every year

Tags: c#, cron, .net-3.5, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I am using quartz cron expressions in C# for scheduling jobs and i am unable to find an expression that would execute the job every thursday and friday of april every year. I used this expression but it executes on thursdays only. I want it on thrusdays and fridays:

0 19 15 ? 4 5#1 *

Please advice.

Comment: See this http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score -1):

Like this.

0 19 15 ? 4 5,6 *

But the CRON expression that you're using suggests that you only want the job to fire on the first occurrence of Thrusday and Friday for April, and specifying several occurrences for day-of-week is not supported in Quartz 2.x.

Refer http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html

I would suggest using 2 separate expressions.

Comment: Please remember to vote if this answers your question.

Comment: I want it to happen only once in April and this should happen every year :(

Comment: Alternatively, here's a little experimental project that can handle several occurrences for day-of-week, if you want to check it out. https://github.com/tswanepoel/crongadgetry

Comment: Your question mentions Thursday and Friday.  Do you mean both, or how must it be decided which one?

Comment: Both. The exact requirement is, I want the schedule to get executed on thursday and friday of April 2nd week and 3rd week. This should happen every year.

Comment: Then I'm afraid my current answer remains.